# Is there a way to get Azure Subscription ID programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We would like to create some Azure resources using Azure Rest APIs through a C# program. We are able to get access token by following the below msdn doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code .
But the Azure Rest APIs also requires Subscription ID which we are not able to get. Is there a way we can get it through program?

Thanks

Balaji

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below request URI to get list of subscriptions for a tenant. https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01

Please refer to [Get Subscription List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for Solution, it worked for me. Don't understand why it was not accepted as correct Answer.